# How to access CoordinateMatrix entries directly in Spark?

Tags: matrix, apache-spark, distributed-computing, sparse-matrix

I want to store a big sparse matrix using Spark, 
so I tried to use `CoordinateMatrix`, since it is a distributed matrix.

However, I have not found a way to access each entry directly such as this way:

```
apply(int x, int y)
```

I only found the functions like:

```
public RDD<MatrixEntry> entries()
```

In this case, I have to loop over the entries to find out the one I want, which is not efficient way.

Has anyone used `CoordinateMatrix` before ?

What should I do to get each entry from `CoordinateMatrix` efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is you don't. RDDs, and `CoordinateMatrix` is more or less a wrapper around the `RDD[MatrixEntry]`, are not well suited for random access. Moreover RDDs are immutable so you cannot simply modify a single entry. If it is your requirement you're probably looking at the wrong technology.

There is some limited support for random access if you use `PairRDD`. If such a RDD is partitioned you can use `lookup` method to efficiently recover a single value:

```
val n = ??? // Number of partitions
val pairs = mat.
    entries.
    map{case MatrixEntry(i, j, v) => ((i, j), v)}.
    partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(n))
pairs.lookup((1, 1))
```