# Does spark dataframe have a "row name" for each row like pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to use Spark DataFrames to operate on two DataFrames indexing by row name.  In pandas, we can do

```
df.loc(['aIndex', 'anotherIndex'])
```

to select two rows in the df by the index (or name of the row). How to achieve this in Spark DataFrame? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no row indexing in Spark. Spark Data Frames are more like tables in relational database so if you want to access specific row you have to filter:

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
    [("Bob", 5), ("Alice", 6), ("Chuck", 4)], ("name", "age"))

df.where("name in ('Bob', 'Alice')")
df.where((df.name == "Bob") | (df.name == "Alice"))
```

Comment: Thanks zero323. I will go with filtering then.

Comment: Sure. The closest thing you get to random access is `lookup` on `PairRDD` (see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31619814/1560062)) but it means loosing all the benefits of the Catalyst optimizer